# IE10 shows wrong version

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

I have some weird problem, i installed internet explorer 10 on windows 7 32 bit system.

Now when i check using `Sys.Browser.version` in javascript it shows version is 6.

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you running in compatibility mode?  That might return an older browser version.  -- although I'm not sure if you can switch to compatibility mode in .NET.

Comment: i'm on 7 64 so show me what you are looking at. also are you sure that's just not the ua string?

Comment: No i m not running compatibility mode, i have used http://www.browser-version.com for verification, it shows IE6 and my OS is Windows XP !!!